# My java game runs in slow motion on different computers

Tags: java, loops

I am developing a game, and just wanted to test it on a different computer to check if the resolutions are ok and all that stuff but noticed one big problem, the game runs in slow motion for some reason... Not laggy, but slow motion..
My game loop is a temporary:

```
while(gameisRunnin){
     doStuff();
     Thread.sleep(1000/60);
```

But after the test, I've tried to check how much time does it take to do the `doStuff();` code and I tested it like this:

```
while(gameisRunnin){
     long startT = System.currentTimeMillis();
     doStuff();
     long stopT = System.currentTimeMillis();
     System.out.println(stopT-startT);
     Thread.sleep(1000/60);
```

The result it gives me is 0, on both computers, (On the one I am developing the game which runs in the perfect speed, and on the pc that it runs in slow motion..
Also I tested it with nano time, it gives me like 50000-80000 on both computes too (pretty much same result.
Seriously what's up? Could a superman save me?

UPDATE:
Ok so when I run the game on the other computer NOT on full screen, it's runs fine, but when it is on full screen, it's slowmotion
Update:
Looks like I am the superhero here, I've set the displaymode the refresh rate to unknown, I guess that was the whole problem...

Comment: Side note: Use `System.nanoTime()` instead of `System.currentTimeMillis()` to measure time differences

Comment: Oooh, the good old days... If you had a 25MHz 286, you had to disable "Turbo" to be able to play Kings Quest I properly...

Comment: test how long `Thread.sleep(1000/60);` takes

Comment: Fast computer = less time for doStuff(), slow computer = more time for doStuff(). You can add a time/fps dependancy for number of iterations in doStuff() so it iterates more if it lags more (probably causing a self-empowering lag). So if it waits for 50ms after last step, it iterates 5 times. If it waits for 20ms after last step, iterates for 2 times. But there is a chance that the time per step will converge if you use a suitable  time ---> iteration number conversion.

Comment: don't do the sleep part as constant, do some benchmarking before starting the main work and decide the waiting part by the benchmark results

Comment: Do you guys even read the post fully? I've tested it with nano time and it game me the same result on both pcs, about 70,000 which is 0.07 ms

Comment: Also yes I've tested the thread.sleep it gave the same time on both computers too

Comment: Is the actual logic performed on the same thread? Your timings indicate that it should run fine. Maybe you are doing some computation that is being executed on the main (GUI) thread?

Comment: As a general tip:  Don't block the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread) - the GUI will 'freeze' when that happens. Instead of calling `Thread.sleep(n)` implement a Swing `Timer` for repeating tasks or a `SwingWorker` for long running tasks.  See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details.

Comment: As I said, the `Thread.sleep();` is temporary

Comment: And the tests seemed to be in the right threads, I've got two threads going, one is the client, and the other is the game it's self. I've got everything organized...

Comment: Fixed, if interested, read the post update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is that the refresh rate of the game wasn't supported by the monitor, changing the refresh-rate from 60 to `DisplayMode.REFRESH_RATE_UNKNOWN` fixes the slowmotion problem.

Answer (score 2):

You've to use something what is usually called "delta time". Basically it means, that you measure how long it takes to do one iteration of the game loop and then use this number for all the movements.

This is because of the different count of FPS on different computers. Instead of moving objects for just constant amount of pixels, you're defining speed and calculating the actual size of movement dynamically.

Short example:

```
public void gameLoop() {
    long initialTime = System.nanoTime();

    game.redraw();
    game.update(System.nanoTime() - initialTime);
}

// inside the class Game
public void update(long deltaTime) {
    someObject.moveToRight(deltaTime * speed);
}
```

Comment: But the problem is that I was about to start making the advanced FPS system using delta time but first I wanted to test the speeds, both computers giving me the same nanotime (more or less) but the game for some reason runs in one pc in slow motion and in the other in normal motion

Comment: I'd suggest to try implement delta time first (the simplest experiment with one moving rectangle is just enough). You'll see if it acts the same or not. This problem may be caused by a lot of things and unfortunately I'm not able to help you without reading the whole code and/or knowing all consequences.

Answer (score 0):

Read this article: [click here](http://gafferongames.com/game-physics/fix-your-timestep/)

Also, as a side note, use **System.nanoTime()** because System.getTimeMillis() isn't as accurate.

Comment: And then ignore the article and use a `ScheduledExecutorService`.